# How to display the author field when i already displayed the comments?

Tags: php, comments, author

I made the comment form and displayed it but i want to display by the same way and the author. I want any user to can type an author name for every new comment. No need to be logged in. How to display the author field? I want to display So here is my php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['addComment']))
    {
            $post_id = $_POST['post'];
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $author = $_POST['author'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (post_id, comment, author) VALUES('$post_id','$comment', '$author')") or die (mysql_error);
}

        ?>
```

And here is the forms with the php :

```
<div id="comments">
<?php 
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE post_id ='$post_id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
        while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
            ?>
<ul class="commentlist">
          <li class="comment_odd">
            <div class="author"><img class="avatar" src="images/demo/avatar.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /><span class="name"><a href="#"><?php echo $comment['author']; ?></a></span> <span class="wrote">wrote:</span></div>
            <p><?php echo $comment['comment']; ?><br /><br /></p>
          </li>


        <?php
        }
        ?>

        Коментар:<br />
        <form action="" method="author">
<p>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="22" />
            <label for="name"><small>Name (required)</small></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $_GET['author']; ?>" />
          </p>
        </form>
<form action="" method="post">

          <p>
            <textarea name="comment" id="commentField" cols="100%" rows="10"></textarea><br />
            <label for="comment" style="display:none;"><small>Comment (required)</small></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="<?php echo $_GET['post']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="addComment" value="Добави" />
          </p>
          </form>
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: how to display the author field ? When any user type his nick name in the author form i want this nick to be displayed uppon the comment of the user

Comment: If you want it to be real time messaging, then you need JavaScript. or if you want PHP to handle it, then you need to INSERT the comment in database and then display the way you have it now

Comment: Yes i want PHP to handle it and yes i inserted the comments in db... I have form where users to add comments like any news site, after an user types a comment, the comment is saved into the DB and after that is placed on the web page. So i want to make the same with the author field. When the user type his nick into the field, the nick to be saved in the DB and then placed to the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['addComment']) && $_POST['addComment'] != '')
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    $q = mysql_query("YOUR INSERT STATMENTHERE");
}
```

Then modify your select statement to include the author. Assuming the field is called author in your db

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT comment, author FROM comments WHERE post_id ='$post_id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    .....
}
```

and now you have $comment['author'], echo it where you want

Comment: it's says [b]"Notice: Undefined index: author in C:\xampp\htdocs\MatchZone\read_more.php on line 18" [/b]
Line 18 is this :   $author = $_POST['author'];